# Elegant way to write this kind of for loop in java

Tags: java, loops

Currently, i'm just using this:

```
for (ClassX value : listabc) {
    if (value.Id.equals(currentId)) {
        return value;
    } else if (value.Id.equals(defaultId)) {
        def = value;
    }
}
if (def != null) {
    return def;
}
return listabc.get(0);
```

For a given currentId and defaultId, loop through the listabc, if listabc has currentId, return it, else if it has defaultId, return it, else, return the first element of the list.

Notice that if listabc has both currentId and defaultId, currentId is the one which should be returned.

this code looks a bit ugly, could anyone help to provide a elegant one? my brain just stop working..

Comment: maybe this belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That's about the best you can do.

Comment: The variable names aren't in the Java style, and checking that the list isn't null (and has one element) before the last return might be a good idea. Also, of what type are your `Id`'s?

Comment: You might also switch to a `SortedSet` and just use contains for your id/defaultId.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belong to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RafaEl I didn't know that we have a place for Code Review, thank you for the tip.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thank you, Id is just a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write it a little neater:

```
ClassX def;
for (ClassX value : listabc) {
   if (value.Id.equals(currentId)) return value;
   if (value.Id.equals(defaultId)) def = value;
}
return def == null ? listabc.get(0) : def;
```

Comment: removing bracket in `if` statement doesn't make it elegant. it is a bad coding habit

Comment: Well, that's a matter of opinion. Personally, I think it's fine if it's on the same line.

Comment: OK, thank you, at least I can use "return def == null ? listabc.get(0) : def;" to make it a bit neater. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need `def`, here is a way:

```
ClassX def = null;
for (ClassX value : listabc) { // Do a null check here on listabc
    if (value != null && value.Id.equals(currentId)) {
        return value;
    } 
    def = def == null && value != null && value.Id.equals(defaultId) value ? null;
 }
 return def != null ? def : listabc.get(0);
```

Comment: Note that you want to check for `value != null` before `value.Id.equals`.